# Difference between "deed" and "doing" in the context of judgement

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, differences

There is already a [question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/138761/141682) about difference between "act" and "deed". My question will be similar. I want to know what is the difference between words "deed" and "doing" when we judge about other people. For example:

- A good deed.
- A good doing.
- A bad deed.
- A bad doing.

Which words is more popular and recognizable? The "deed" looks more rare and oldschool for me.

Comment: Off the top of my head, all deeds are doings, but not all doings are deeds. However, I would not use them interchangeably, especially in cases of established phrasing, e.g., "a good deed." If you take a look at the definitions for [deed](https://www.google.com.tw/search?q=deed&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab&gfe_rd=cr&ei=06LbWM60Ocr48AfQqb_ADQ) and [doing](https://www.google.com.tw/search?q=doing&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab&gfe_rd=cr&ei=kKLbWKvMHsr48AfQqb_ADQ), a few key words should become pretty obvious. Meanwhile, I'm trying to think of when a deed is not a doing....

Comment: I have never heard of a good or bad doing.